# Is there another way to retrieve data in url rather than URI->SEGMENT?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Example:

> ...scms/contracts/set_pm/3/Monthly

this is the URL and i want to get the word monthly...I cant use uri->segment in my view so I'm asking if there's other way

Comment: Why you can't use uri->segment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be something like this

```
$actual_link = current_url();
$slashes = explode("/",$actual_link);
echo $element = $slashes[count($slashes)-1];
```

Answer (score 2):

Just retrieve the `current_url()` and explode it with `/`, but why do such cumbersome process when you have lots of options provided by `CI`.

If you cant use `$this->uri` in your view just put that segment in a variable and load the view like this:

```
$data['segment'] = $this->uri->segment(5);  //your segment here you want in your view
$this->load->view('view', $data);
```

Now, you will get the segment in your view as `$segment`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `explod` function in PHP to get a tab with your string in input.

```
$tab = explode("/", $url);

$last = end($tab);
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering contracts is your controller file name and set_pm is your function then you can also fetch it like this:

```
class Contracts extends CI_Controller {
    function set_pm($id, $interval)
    {
     echo $id; //prints 3
     echo $interval; // prints Monthly
    }
}
```